# variable set in blade that I am not setting

Tags: laravel

I am trying to display certain content in my blade files based on if variables are set. But variables are being set that I'm not setting.

I have GameController.php:

```
use App\Models\Game;

class GameController extends Controller
{

    public function index() {

        $games = Game::latest()->get();

        return view('game.index', [
            'games' => $games
        ]);

    }
...
```

and then in the layout blade file I do this:

```
@isset($game->name)
<h1>{{ $game->name }}</h1>
@endisset
```

So I'm setting $games, but I am NOT setting $game. however, $game is set. I want this header to show if I do a show() and $game would be set, but it shouldn't be showing in the index() where $game is not set. Is this normal behavior, and if so what's a better way for me to handle this?

Comment: try to print what inside `$game` variable with `dd`

Comment: Is `$game` set somewhere else, View Composer or something? Do you have a `@foreach` above that code that might set `$game`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the issue. It was lack of understanding of how @extend and @section work.

index.blade.php extends layout.blade.php

```
@extends ('layout')
```

it appears all of index processes before layout. Because of that a foreach in index, despite technically being below the header if you were to view source on the web page, was processing before the header and setting $game. I just refactored the variable used in the foreach and that resolved my issue.

Thank you kerbh0lz, you technically helped me find it.

Answer (score -1):

```
$games = Game::latest()->get();
```

in code above `get()` returns collection (may be called array) of games, and you will need `@foreach` directive in blade template to loop through the games collection.

if you want only one latest game then you should use `$games = Game::latest()->first();`